# Breakpoints are not hitting while debugging F# console application in VSCode using Mono Debug extension

Tags: f#, mono, visual-studio-code

I created a test console application and trying to debug it using VSCode and Mono Debug extension.

fsharp code :

```
module TestFharp

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Args %A" argv
    let x = 5
    printf "hello world"
    0
```

launch.json :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "mono",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/FSharp/test/TestFharp/bin/Debug/TestFharp.exe",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "env": {},
            "externalConsole": false,
            "stopOnEntry": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "mono",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 55555
        }
    ]
}
```

output of the DEBUG CONSOLE window

```
mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:61724 C:/FSharp/test/TestFharp/bin/Debug/TestFharp.exe 
Args [||]
hello world
```

- Do I need to make any other settings to hit the breakpoint?
- What's the difference between exe file inside build folder and \projectFolder\bin\Debug?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between exe file inside build folder and \projectFolder\bin\Debug

`exe` file in `build` directory is created by FAKE's build script (`build.fsx` file) [invoked in Ionide with `Ctrl + F5` / `FAKE: Build default` command]

`exe` in `\projectFolder\bin\Debug` is standard MsBuild output. In Ionide you can invoke MsBuild directly using `MsBuild: Build project` command.

Both `exe` files are the same (FAKE is using MsBuild under the hood), it's just matter of preference and whether you want to run some additional operations on build (like testing) - FAKE allows you to define more complex build processes, MsBuild just compile app.

Depending on which method you use to build your app, you need to point at right `exe` in `launch.json`

I'd also set `externalConsole` to `true`.

Otherwise, it looks good, `F5` should start your application and debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The launch.json contains two configurations: one for launching the target (name: "Launch"), one for attaching to an already launched target (name: "Attach"). They are independent from each other.

In the "Launch" configuration no "port" is specified and mono-debug will use a random port when launching mono and will attach to that same port. So these ports are always in sync by definition.

In the "Attach" configuration a port is specified because mono-debug cannot know  the debug port mono was started with.

So the launch configurations are both fine and the first one should be easier to use because it launches mono and attaches the debugger in one go.

If breakpoints are not hit, could it be that the TestFharp.exe was not build for debugging?

Answer (score -1):

The attach configuration you have specified is using port 55555, but the way you're running your app specifies 61724 for the debugger, so try getting those two in sync

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The debugger grabs a new port everytime, how can i force it to use a specific one? Thanks

Comment: Opened an issue for this in github.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mono-debug/issues/23